# Wxpython: How to access variables between across classes/panels

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am new to wxpython and OOPS concepts.
My requirement is a window as shown in the image.
Currently problem is how can i access the frame  Ip address,username and password entered by the user  in panel number 2 classes and functions.

Also I need a suggestion if the method I'm using to switch panels using menu bar is right or wrong ?I will be using  around **14 to 15** different panel2 layouts ..Each payout will have different lists,checkboxes and textboxes..

Please guide me or provide suggestions..

Thanks in advance.

![Layout of the window:Frame(Black): accepts ip add,username,password.
Panle2(Orange):Will need to switch to different  panel(Just a portion of the frame) or contents of panel should change depending on the user selecting the menu bar .Text Box of Frame 3(Red):Shows the output depending on the panel 2 selection and execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avafv.jpg)

Please find the Code I'm using as below(Executing):

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel


class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
""""""

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
    screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
    screenWidth = screenSize[0]
    screenHeight = screenSize[1]
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,pos=(0,175),size=(screenWidth,570),style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    radio3 = wx.RadioButton(parent=self, label="Enable", name='radio3', pos=(0,50))      
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
""""""

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, parent):
    screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
    screenWidth = screenSize[0]
    screenHeight = screenSize[1]
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,pos=(0,175),size=(screenWidth,570),style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    radio3 = wx.RadioButton(parent=self, label="Disable", name='radio3', pos=(10,150))      

class GUI(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent,id,title):

    # BOA generated methods
    #First retrieve the screen size of the device
    screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
    screenWidth = screenSize[0]
    screenHeight = screenSize[1]
    #Create a frame
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=screenSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
    self.SetBackgroundColour('#d8d8d8')
    self.ipt=wx.StaticText(parent=self,id=-1,label="IDRAC IP Address",pos=(10,30))
    font1 = wx.Font(12,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL)
    self.ipt.SetFont(font1)
    self.ipaddress=wx.TextCtrl(parent=self,pos=(155,30),size=(150,25))#Question1:how can I access ipaddress obtained here in class panelone and class paneltwo?
    self.usert=wx.StaticText(parent=self,id=-1,label="User Name  ",pos=(10,65))
    font2 = wx.Font(12,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL)
    self.usert.SetFont(font2)
    self.username=wx.TextCtrl(parent=self,pos=(155,65),size=(150,25))
    self.passt=wx.StaticText(parent=self,id=-1,label="Password  ",pos=(10,100))
    font3 = wx.Font(12,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL)
    self.passt.SetFont(font3)
    self.password=wx.TextCtrl(parent=self,pos=(155,100),size=(150,25),style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
    self.checkbtn=wx.Button(parent=self,label='Connect' ,pos=(320,45),size=(65,65))
    self.checkbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.connect)
    self.con=wx.StaticText(parent=self,id=-1,label="Connectivity Status",pos=(400,30))
    self.textarea=wx.TextCtrl(parent=self,style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_MULTILINE,pos=wx.Point(10,760),size=(screenWidth,270))
    self.status=wx.TextCtrl(parent=self,style=wx.TE_READONLY,pos=wx.Point(575,30),size=(170,25))
    self.con=wx.StaticText(parent=self,id=-1,label="Connectivity Status",pos=(400,30))

    font3 = wx.Font(12,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL)
    self.con.SetFont(font3)
    self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
    self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
    self.panel_two.Hide()
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,
                                              "Switch Panels",
                                              "Some text")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels,
              switch_panels_menu_item)
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
 def connect(self,event):
    print "Connect"

def onSwitchPanels(self, event):

    if self.panel_one.IsShown():
       self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
       self.panel_one.Hide()
       self.panel_two.Show()
    else:
       self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
       self.panel_one.Show()
       self.panel_two.Hide()
    self.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = wx.App()
wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="BIOS/iDRAC tokens")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You have a lot of unreadable code here.  Ask one question, fix your formatting, post only the necessary code, as well as your expected and actual output or behavior.

Comment: @Scott I've edited the program,it executes now..Please let me know if you can help as to how the inputs obtained in class GUI(i.e ip address ,username,pswd)can be accessed in the classes panelone and paneltwo..

Comment: I also need a suggestion if the method I'm using to switch panels using menu bar is right or wrong ..I'm a bit concerned as I will have around 14-15 different panels for that section...It will be really helpful if someone could guide on this also

Answer (score 0):

You can access the frame attributes in your panel classes by using e.g.

```
parent.username
```

How will you handle the 15 or so panels, will there be 15 menu options, or ....?

Using Hide/Show is one option, maybe a book type widget (e.g. notebook) with the different panels would be another option.

"wx.InitAllImageHandlers" shouldn't be needed any more unless you use a really old wxPython version.

BTW, the indent levels of your code are still not correct.